# Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)) in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm facing issues while parsing JSON strings with Jackson in some cases.

```
String jsonString = "{\"Age\":40, \"Name\":\"Sample User\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(jsonString,JsonNode.class);

System.out.println(jsonstirng)
{"Age":40, "Name":"Sample User"}
```

The above code works well when I pass the `jsonString` value.

In some cases, I need to escape invalid string characters like `",'` etc

For escaping I am using **Apache** `StringEscapeUtils`.

```
String escapedString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(jsonStirng);
```

Escaped String output

```
{\"Age\":40,\"Name\":\"Sample User\"}
```

When I pass the escaped string to `mapper` its throws an Unexpected character exception.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(escapedString,JsonNode.class);
```

Exception

```
Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Actually, I'm parsing ModSecurity audit logs. The response body of the audit log has  (HTML, CSS, javascript, etc)  stuff that's why I need to escape the JSON string other wise its breaks the JSON format.

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes in that string? The real Json string should not have escapes in it. Print the `jsonString` you have in your first line and you'll see that internally it doesn't have any escaping.

Comment: The question has very confusing description, it is not even compilable and escaping magically changes Age from 40 to 33. Please check and show real code. But I could only assume that you are quoting something wrong.

Comment: @kan typo mistake. Now am update it kindly have a look.

Comment: You should not escape json string itself, you only need to escape raw strings which will be placed as values of a json formatted document.

Comment: According to your last line in the question, you need to escape the "stuff", but not a JSON.

Comment: @kan but that stuff is part of json.

Comment: @basitraza It could not be part of a json if it is not escaped already. Show your stuff so we could see what you actually have and want to do. The `jsonString` in your current example is already escaped as it should, no need to touch it.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of escaping a String is to make it unparsable as piece of JSON.

In your cause you are replacing all the `"` with `\"` so that it can be used inside a String value and the parser will NOT see it as part of the JSON.

e.g. this is just one field and value;

```
"myJson": "{\"Age\":40,\"Name\":\"Sample User\"}"
```

what you can't do is the following which is why you need this method. It can't tell the difference between `"` which starts/ends the string and the `"` inside the string.

```
"myJson": "{"Age":40,"Name":"Sample User"}"
```

If you then try to parse this escaped String, it shouldn't be able to parse it.

---

EDIT: Here is an example

```
String text = "{\"Age\":40,\"Name\":\"Sample User\"}";
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(text);
System.out.println("escaped= " + escaped);
String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(escaped);
System.out.println("unescaped= " + unescaped);
```

prints

```
escaped= {\"Age\":40,\"Name\":\"Sample User\"}
unescaped= {"Age":40,"Name":"Sample User"}
```

you can see that the escaped string has `\"` however the unescaped string doesn't.  If you are still seeing `\` I would assume the String hasn't been unescaped.

Comment: Actually Am parsing ModSecurity audit logs with jackson. Am also getting response header and response body. Response body has  (html,css,javascript etc)  stuff that's why I need to escape json string other wise its breaks the json format.

Comment: @basitraza agreed, escaping is for safely placing a String inside a value.  To parse such a string, you have to unescape it first to reverse what it does. Note: there is more than one way to escape out a string, so it's best to use a matching unescape

Comment: what you recommend in this scenario. Am tried different escaping pattern but nothing changed. Escaping single quote ` ' ` works in some cases but not in all.

Comment: @basitraza You should be able to call escape on a String and use it as a value, when extracting the value you have to call unescape.  Which character did this not work on?

Comment: I did unescaping before parsing but jackson object mapper throw Unexpected character exception, Actually its already broken json string due to invalid characters

Comment: @basitraza I have added an example.

Comment: `
String jsonString = "{\"Age\":40, \"Name\":\"Sample '\" User\"}";
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(jsonString);
 `

Comment: unescaping works in case of valid json string, but not works if invalid character in json string

Comment: @basitraza if you escaped the string correctly, there shouldn't be any invalid characters for the contents of a value. This is the purpose of escaping the String.

Comment: thanks for you help. Is regex is good approach for un-escaping

Comment: @basitraza I would use the `unescapeJson` as I suggested.  If you don't know how it was escaped, you need to understand what the mapping is and then work out a solution.

Comment: @basitraza Using regex for json is very similar as for html, so just read instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/438742